# Issue with JFrame focus when disabling JButton

Tags: java, jframe, focus, jbutton

I'm having a really strange issue with my Java Application. I'm using Netbeans, and so I have a frameview with a main panel that has some buttons to choose a serial port and connect to it. It also has a menu bar to open up a bunch of different frames.

The problem is: sometimes when I open up another frame, if I click back onto my main panel, the focus is immediately taken back to the opened frame (not the panel I just clicked on). When it does this, it also highlights the JComponents in this opened frame, basically Tabbing through them with each mouse click and release on the main panel. So to summarize, the focus keeps jumping away from the frame I click on. And i'm using autoRequestFocus.

I narrowed it down such that I found this only happened with the first frame I opened after I had hit the connect to serial port button. So I would:
Start App->Connect to serial port->open different frame from menu bar-> click back onto the main panel, but have my focus immediately returned to the opened frame

So I realized it had to be something in my Connect to serial port JToggleButton method. Finally, I've found that if I comment out one line of code, the issue is solved. That line is:

```
refreshPortsButton.setEnabled(false);
```

The `refreshPortsButton` populates the list of available serial ports, and I don't want people to be doing that when they've connected.

I have a workaround by instead setting the button's visibility to be false, but I'd rather just gray out the button and this behaviour is so bizarre to me, I really want to figure it out. How could a buttons enabled state possibly mess up how things focus. 
Here's an SSCCE, I tried to simplify it as much as possible, sorry for the long initComponents

FocusSSCCEApp.java

```
package focussscce;

import org.jdesktop.application.Application;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class FocusSSCCEApp extends SingleFrameApplication {

    @Override protected void startup() {
        show(new FocusSSCCEView(this));
    }


    @Override protected void configureWindow(java.awt.Window root) {
    }


    public static FocusSSCCEApp getApplication() {
        return Application.getInstance(FocusSSCCEApp.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(FocusSSCCEApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

FocusSSCCEView.java

```
package focussscce;

import java.awt.Color;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

/**
 * The application's main frame.
 */
public class FocusSSCCEView extends FrameView {

    public final static Color DARK_GREEN = new Color(0, 150, 0);

    public FocusSSCCEView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);

        initComponents();
        this.getFrame().setResizable(false);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        refreshPortsButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        connectToggleButton = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        javax.swing.JMenu prefMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        javax.swing.JMenuItem prefMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        preferencesFrame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        textField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 50));
        mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(493, 50));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

        org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(focussscce.FocusSSCCEApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(FocusSSCCEView.class);
        refreshPortsButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("refreshPortsButton.text")); // NOI18N
        refreshPortsButton.setName("refreshPortsButton"); // NOI18N
        refreshPortsButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                refreshPortsButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(refreshPortsButton);

        connectToggleButton.setText(resourceMap.getString("connectToggleButton.text")); // NOI18N
        connectToggleButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        connectToggleButton.setFocusable(false);
        connectToggleButton.setName("connectToggleButton"); // NOI18N
        connectToggleButton.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                connectToggleButtonItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(connectToggleButton);

        menuBar.setName("menuBar"); // NOI18N

        prefMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("prefMenu.text")); // NOI18N
        prefMenu.setName("prefMenu"); // NOI18N

        prefMenuItem.setText(resourceMap.getString("prefMenuItem.text")); // NOI18N
        prefMenuItem.setName("prefMenuItem"); // NOI18N
        prefMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                prefMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        prefMenu.add(prefMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(prefMenu);

        preferencesFrame.setTitle(resourceMap.getString("preferencesFrame.title")); // NOI18N
        preferencesFrame.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        preferencesFrame.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 70));
        preferencesFrame.setName("preferencesFrame"); // NOI18N
        preferencesFrame.setResizable(false);
        preferencesFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

        textField1.setName("textField1"); // NOI18N
        textField1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                textField1MouseEntered(evt);
            }
        });
        preferencesFrame.getContentPane().add(textField1);

        textField2.setName("textField2"); // NOI18N
        textField2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                textField2MouseEntered(evt);
            }
        });
        preferencesFrame.getContentPane().add(textField2);

        setComponent(mainPanel);
        setMenuBar(menuBar);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void refreshPortsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        //populateCommPort();
    }                                                  

    private void connectToggleButtonItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                     
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

            //connect();
            connectToggleButton.setText("Disconnect");
            connectToggleButton.setForeground(DARK_GREEN);
            refreshPortsButton.setEnabled(false); //Disabling this remedies the problem
        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            //disconnect();
            refreshPortsButton.setEnabled(true);
            connectToggleButton.setText("Connect");
            connectToggleButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }                                                    

    private void textField1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        textField1.setToolTipText( textField1.getText() );
    }                                       

    private void prefMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        preferencesFrame.setVisible( true );
        preferencesFrame.requestFocusInWindow();
        preferencesFrame.pack();
    }                                            

    private void textField2MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        textField2.setToolTipText( textField2.getText() );
    }                                       

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton connectToggleButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    private javax.swing.JFrame preferencesFrame;
    private javax.swing.JButton refreshPortsButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `refreshPortsButton.revalidate()`?

Comment: I just tried it now, but it's still doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when there is a focus-able component on your frame, java paints the focus rectangle over it.

I added another button and once the **refreshPortsButton** button is disabled, the focus automatically jumped to the next focus-able one.

I disabled the focusPaint on the refreshPortsButton and it worked fine. You can enable it back once you enabled the button.

```
private void bConnectActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    refresh.setEnabled(!refresh.isEnabled());
    refresh.setFocusPainted(refresh.isEnabled());
    if (refresh.isEnabled()) {
        refresh.requestFocus();
    }
    b2.setEnabled(!b2.isEnabled());
    b2.setFocusPainted(b2.isEnabled());
}
```

Comment: Ohh, now I'm realizing what focus actually means haha. Ya, that was definitely the issue, so I ended up putting in `refreshPortsButton.setFocusable(false)` with it, and then settting it true once it was enabled again.